# Castle Windsor delegate-based factory: passing parameters to the constructor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

So, I have an `IConnectionFactory` interface, implemented by the `NMSConnectionFactory` class with a constructor that looks like this:

```
public NMSConnectionFactory(string providerURI, params object[] constructorParams)
```

I need to create these on demand, and the `providerURI` will only be known at runtime.
So I'm trying to use a delegate-based factory that creates `IConnectionFactory`s for me (let's call it `connectionFactoryProvider`).

After reading the Castle documentations, I've tried this:
My other class's constructor depends on this factory as such:

```
public ActiveMqSessionPool(Func<string, IConnectionFactory> connectionFactoryProvider)
{...}
```

Inside this constructor, I use the provider to create `IConnectionFactory`s as such:

```
var connectionFactory = _connectionFactoryProvider("my destination");
```

However, when I run this last line I get an error saying that the NMSConnectionFactory is waiting on these dependencies:

```
- Parameter 'providerURI' which was not provided. Did you forget to set the dependency?

- Service 'System.Object[]' which was not registered.
```

How can I pass the `providerURI` to the NMSConnectionFactory constructor?

This is what my component registration looks like so far:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IConnectionFactory>()
                                    .ImplementedBy<NMSConnectionFactory>())
                 .Register(Component.For<ISessionPool>()
                                    .ImplementedBy<ActiveMqSessionPool>().LifeStyle.Transient)
                 .AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
```

Do I need to configure something else? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your NMSConnectionFactory's constructor has the signature (string, object[]), so your factory method needs to have the same I think.

Try changing:

```
public ActiveMqSessionPool(Func<string, IConnectionFactory> connectionFactoryProvider)
```

to:

```
public ActiveMqSessionPool(Func<string, object[], IConnectionFactory> connectionFactoryProvider
```

Comment: That worked. I ended up creating a dedicated delegate for this, since I wanted to make the `object[]` parameter optional, and you can't do that with `Func`. Thanks

Comment: Here's the delegate, for future reference: `internal delegate IConnectionFactory ConnectionFactoryProvider(string providerURI, params object[] constructorParams);`