# Castle Windsor: How to inject the collection of all factories?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Using Castle Windsor, I want to get the collection of all factories that implement a particular interface.

Say you have the following type hierarchy:

```
public interface IAnimal { }
public class Cat : IAnimal { }
public class Dog : IAnimal { }
```

using `TypedFactoryFacility` I am able to inject a `Func<IAnimal>` that acts as a *factory* to create animal instances (with transient life cycle). I can also use `CollectionResolver` to resolve a *collection* of animals with singleton life cycles. But in the following example, it seems that you cannot combine the effects of `TypedFactoryFacility` and `CollectionResolver` to resolve a collection of factories.

```
public class Zoo
{
    public Zoo(IEnumerable<Func<IAnimal>> animalFactories)
    {
        foreach (Func<IAnimal> factory in animalFactories)
        {
            IAnimal animal = factory();
            Console.WriteLine(animal.GetType());
        }
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
        container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel));

        container.Register(Component.For<IAnimal>().ImplementedBy<Cat>().LifestyleTransient());
        container.Register(Component.For<IAnimal>().ImplementedBy<Dog>().LifestyleTransient());
        container.Register(Component.For<Zoo>());

        container.ResolveAll<IAnimal>();
        container.Resolve<Zoo>();
    }
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
Component Zoo has a dependency on System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Func`1[IAnimal]], which could not be resolved.
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do these steps :

1. Register an interface as factory with the lifetime that suits your needs. The interface has no impleentation because it is [castle typed factory facility.](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) I register such providers as singletons :

   Component.For().AsFactory()

I intentionally name it provider because it does not create new intances by some logic but provides you the already registered instances.

2. The interface must look like this :

   public interface IAnimalFactoryProvider
       {
           IEnumerable<IAnimalFactory> GetAllAnimalFactories();
           void Release(IAnimalFactory animalFactory);
       }
3. Then you put IModuleModelInitializerProvider in a ctor that you want it injected and then get all hte instances through the method GetAllAnimalFactories().
4. Then depending on your IAnimal factories you may release them after use or if they are singletons too you can just leave them and Castle will dispose them when your application quits.

Another approach - typed factory as delegate is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096149/castle-windsor-delegate-based-factory-passing-parameters-to-the-constructor), [here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Typed-Factory-Facility-delegate-based-factories&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1), [here](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/01/10-advanced-windsor-tricks-1.html), [here](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/01/10-advanced-windsor-tricks-1a-delegate.html) and [here](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/01/21/software-factories-2.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need the factory to be a deledate for some reason :(